# Coluna BLOB 'sobre' não pode ter um valor padrão (default)

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, default

Ao tentar manter uma coluna como podendo ser nula, `mediumText`, e adicionar um valor 'as defined', ele retorna:

> Coluna BLOB 'sobre' não pode ter um valor padrão (default)

Por que eu não posso? Que coisas implicam nisso? Como posso resolver isso para permitir uma coluna opcional no MySQL do tipo `mediumText` (ou outra que supra a necessidade) e tenha um valor padrão como "Não fala muito", por exemplo?

Comment: O que aconteceu? Porque o voto contra? Como eu posso arrumar, melhorar...

Comment: Não fui eu quem negativou sua pergunta, meu chute seria que alguém votou negativamente porque se trata de um erro de sintaxe. No caso coluna blob não aceita valor padrão e não tem muito mais o que discutir sobre isso, exceto resolver via trigger no banco ou na sua própria aplicação.

Comment: @user97897 A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

Qual seria o valor padrão para um `BLOB` já que ele pode conter qualquer coisa?

Não sendo possível definir um valor padrão não pode usar esta cláusula neste tipo de coluna.

Por outro lado se a coluna aceitar nulos, aí o valor padrão é fácil, o `NULL` é o padrão e aí pode usar, uma solução é usar um `NULL`, porém eu só faria isto se precisa disto e não outra coisa, colunas que permitem nulos devem ser evitadas, eu não usaria só para deixar ter uma valor padrão. E nem é o valor que deseja.

Se o que você quer é colocar um texto, então coloque o tipo apropriado. Só entenda que `TEXT` é o mesmo que um `BLOB` e não aceita valor padrão.

Você pode achar que deveria poder colocar um texto, mas acharam que conceitualmente não fazia sentido. Tem quem discorde.

[Documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html).